# How to reuse an API key specified in `AppDelegate`?

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, google-api

I have started Objective C a few hours ago, apologies if my question is already answered, I could not find anything similar.

I have my API key specified in the `AppDelegate` as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey = "..."]
}
```

As per [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search) this key need to be provided when I query for the nearby locations. Ideally, I would like to have my key in one file, no copy-paste.

Is there way to get the reference to the key from `AppDelegate` and use it in another file? Maybe it should be kept in yet another file and both `AppDelegate` file and the file that calls `Locations API` should query that another file? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250805/wheres-the-best-place-to-store-constants-in-an-ios-app

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reference this key in any other file. The API key is paired with your application's bundle ID to identify it. You should call '+ (BOOL) provideAPIKey:(NSString *)APIKey' exactly once in your application.

Therefore, if you called it in application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, you should be able to use google maps services in any other class.

Take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/ if you want to see some example codes.

However, if you want, to any reason, be able to reuse any object between your class, you should use [Singleton](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html).

The API key, for example is a NSString. Thus, you would declare a class in your .h file like:

```
@interface APIKey : NSObject

+ (APIKey*)sharedInstance;

@property NSString * apiValue;

@end
```

And a .m:

```
@implementation APIKey

+ (APIKey *)sharedInstance{

static APIKey * sharedInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
});
return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

Then you would be able to access 'apiValue' in any class (after import .h file) just calling

```
[[APIKey sharedInstance] apiValue];
```

Or set new values like this:

```
[[APIKey sharedInstance] setApiValue:@"someThingHere"];
```

But, as I said, you don't need this to Google API Key.

Hope this helps.